# Dozer mapping of Lists of Complex Object

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Is there a way to map one List of objects to one List of objects ids? 
I have the following objects:

```
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private List<Section> sections;
    //getters and setters
    ...
}

public class Section {
    private Long id;
    //getters and setters
    ...
}

public class RoleDTO implements Serializable {
    private List<Long> sections;
    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

How can i map this with Dozer XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html)

Dozer XML

```
<field custom-converter-id="mySectionsConverter">
  <a>sections</a>
  <b>sections</b>
</field>
```

Spring XML

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingFiles" value="..." />
    <property name="customConvertersWithId">
        <map>
           <entry key="mySectionsConverter" value-ref="..." />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note: I'm just in the process of removing dozer from my application because I feel that it complicates things. In my opinion a simple java POJO converter class does a much better job than all this XML, custom converters and spring wiring. I've also found cases where it was impossible to reuse a value in a nested converter which caused multiple database hits which weren't required with the POJO solution.

Comment: Thanks, but i was hopping that it can be done only with the mapping avoiding the converters. If i use the converter it will be apply only to this mapping? or it will be applied to all the mappings? because in another mapping i will like to map a Section object to a Section object not to a Long.

Comment: As I said, dozer is a bit rubbish / verbose. Ideally you should remove it all together!!!. I think you'll need the custom converter which will be a couple of lines of code (plus all the xml gubbins). There's nothing stopping you from having a different field mapping from Section to Section for another process.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is not an answer... more of a wish

It would be nice if dozer supported groovy's [spread operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator(*.)). This would be a nice feature request

eg:

```
<field>
    <a>sections*.id</a>
    <b>sections</b>
</field>
```